# Passing node version to grunt-exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-exec

Would anyone know how to pass the current node version into grunt-exec? Currently I have grunt exec setup like the following:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    exec:{
      mocha: {
        cmd:function(version){
          if(semver.gt(version, '0.10')){
            return 'mocha test/index.js';
          } else return 'mocha --harmony test/harmony/index.js';
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

In `grunt.registerTask()`, I have tried using a bash command like so

```
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'exec:mocha:$(node version)'
  ]);
```

but of course it doesn't work that way.

I have looked plugins such as `grunt-node-version` but the lack of an actual example doesn't help much.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking up on npmjs.com, I found the perfect module that helped me do a little hack:

Using [node-version](https://github.com/srod/node-version), I was able to pass the version into the function and have semver decide if it's greater than a certain version like so:

```
var version = new (require('node-version').version);
    version = version.getVersion();

    grunt.initConfig({
        exec:{
          mocha: {
            cmd:function(version){
              if(semver.lt(version.toString(), '0.11.0')){
                return 'mocha test/index.js';
              } else return 'mocha --harmony test/harmony/index.js';
            }
          }
        }
     });

     grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'exec:mocha:' + version.long
      ]);
```